# Is there a way to customise bookmark icons in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

So I have these bookmarks in Chrome, and some web pages will not actually set an icon:

[image]

Is there anyway to assign a small icon to them manually?

Comment: I don't know about an extension - in fact, it appears that the UI is very well-isolated from extensions. As an alternative, I'm going to look into UserChrome/UserContent/etc. and I'll get back to you if I figure something out.

Comment: Sorry... looks like I'm switching back to Firefox. I'm sick of not being able to customize menus, icons, toolbar & button placement, etc. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=347016 -- there have been dozens of these threads citing everything from more advanced technical motivation to basic accessibility features for the disabled and Google DGAF.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't think there's a built in way of customizing the favicon, but you can use a chrome extension called [Bookmark Favicon Changer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-favicon-changer/acmfnomgphggonodopogfbmkneepfgnh) which will let you modify it.

Comment: I can confirm that this works. I just did so for https://www.onenote.com/stickynotes

Answer (score 6):

There isn't currently (November 2019) a way to do this natively, although this functionality is a [Chrome feature-request](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/13499485?hl=en) that I would recommend up-voting.

Your options at present are (from easiest to difficult):

- Use an emoji in the bookmark name
- Install a Chrome extension, e.g. [Bookmark Favicon Changer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-favicon-changer/acmfnomgphggonodopogfbmkneepfgnh) or [Favicon Changer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/favicon-changer/ijaabbaphikljkkcbgpbaljfjpflpeoo)
- Create a custom HTML redirect on your PC or server as per [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20190412164144/https://www.minterest.com/how-to-change-chrome-bookmark-icon/)

Answer (score 5):

Q: Is there a way to customise bookmark icons in Chrome?

A: Not easily.

Bookmark icons are stored in an SQLite database in ...
%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Favicons.

The icon images are stored (in png format) in the "image_data" field in "favicon_bitmaps" table. This table is indexed on the "image_id" field (numeric). The "image_id" value can be found in the "icon_mapping" table via the indexed "page_url" field.

Additional notes:
 
1. sometimes there's more than one image per "image_id" (ie when there are different sized images - eg 16x16px, 32x32px)
2. the Favicons file can't be updated (by external applications) while Chrome is running.

Answer (score 0):

This website provides a wise way to achieve this also:

"it’s done by creating an HTML file on your PC or on a web server that redirects to your preferred website (by using simple HTML redirects)."

http://www.minterest.com/how-to-change-chrome-bookmark-icon/

(In fact, that's likely what the "Bookmark Favicon Changer" performs behind the scene, as it requires to enable the option "allow access to file URLs", which also means that the solution does not follow your profile on each PC you log in with Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

I just published the modern version of old "Bookmarks Icon Changer" extension for Chrome.  It allows replacing Bookmarks with emojis for folders as well as bookmarks.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmarks%20emoji/edhimhkligfccgpkiahdmioohofelpgm