# Change Chrome bookmark folder icons

Tags: google-chrome, icons, bookmarks

How can I change the chrome bookmark folder icons?
Right now I'm using a symbolic font:

[image]

Is it somehow possible to create custom icons or include FontAwesome for chrome? I'm using Windows 10.

Answer (score 21):

Although you cant change folder icon, you can rename the folder name to an Emoji so that you can see next to the folder an icon .
For example you can go to https://emojipedia.org/ search for guitar, peak a result, roll down until you'll find "Copy and paste this emoji" .
Just copy and past it to the rename of the folder.

Comment: On Windows you can press `Windows Key + Period` to open the emoji picker. Then start typing to filter emojis.

Answer (score 6):

Choosing custom icons for bookmark folders in the bookmarks bar is not currently possible. If you'd like to see this in the next Chrome upgrade, make sure to start a new thread with your feature request and also submit feedback directly in Chrome.

To submit feedback directly in Chrome:

1. Click the Chrome menu (More)  in the top right corner of the browser.
2. Select Help.
3. Select Report an Issue.
4. Add the details of your feature request.

Comment: This was also the answer 3 years ago for the same question from 2010 :( https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/JRw5QDT3T7U

Comment: @oren  haha..   : )

Answer (score 3):

I answered a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1053584/is-there-a-way-to-customise-bookmark-icons-in-chrome/1497964#1497964).

There isn't currently (November 2019) a way to do this natively, although this functionality is a [Chrome feature-request](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/13499485?hl=en) that I would recommend up-voting.

Your options at present are (from easiest to difficult):

- Use an emoji in the folder name
- Install a Chrome extension, e.g. [Bookmark Favicon Changer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-favicon-changer/acmfnomgphggonodopogfbmkneepfgnh) or [Favicon Changer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/favicon-changer/ijaabbaphikljkkcbgpbaljfjpflpeoo)
- Create a custom HTML redirect on your PC or server as per [this article](https://www.minterest.com/how-to-change-chrome-bookmark-icon/)