# Change Folder Icons in Bookmark Bar on Chromium Based Browsers

Tags: google-chrome, browser, browser-addons, chromium, opera

I have been using Opera for a while and I love the icons style in bookmarks bar:

[image]

Currently icons in Chromium based browsers(Chrome, Vivaldi, Brave, Edge, etc...) are like this:

[image]

I would like to change them to Opera style bookmarks; i.e. just the outline visible, no fill. I'm talking about the actual icon next to the name of the folder.

Comment: As answered here --> https://superuser.com/questions/1209163/change-chrome-bookmark-folder-icons  is not possible and still maybe

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy paste this to your chrome's url bar
   `chrome://flags/#chrome-refresh-2023`
2. Then set it "enabled"
3. Refresh
   Chrome